# Display first Item Highlighted always on recyclerView Adapter without any click of Item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement the code in `bindViewholderMethod` but it wasn't working for me.I'm trying to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` with launch   but it's not working for me. 
My adapter code is here

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final  CarTypesHolder holder,  int position) {
    //  II=0;


    if (II == position) {
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    } else {
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `II` in condition. you can change it to `if (position == 0)` which will change color of the first item.

Comment: @Prashant is correct. You have to change your if condition expression like `position==II` and before it. You have to declare your `II` as  variable with `0` value.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since users have answered there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(position==0){
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    } else {
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

    }
```